# Laravel datatables can't create custom columns

Tags: laravel, datatables, laravel-blade

I have two tables first one simple html with no datatables, second with datables. My purpose transform first table two datatables second. But I had two main problems Grazinimo terminas column is using laravel @if and column Veiksmai using if statemens as well how can i add those as custom columns in second table.
[image: First not dinamical table]

[image]

**First table code**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead class="bg-warning">
        <th>Knygos pavadinimas</th>
        <th>Miestas</th>
        <th>Išdavimo data</th>
        <th>Grąžinimo terminas</th>
        <th>Vardas</th>
        <th>Pavardė</th>
        <th>Kliento nr.</th>
        <th>Veiksmai</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($paskolinimai as $p)
        <input type="hidden"
            value="{{ $skirtumas =  \Carbon\Carbon::parse(\Carbon\Carbon::today()->toDateString())->diffInDays( \Carbon\Carbon::parse( $p->terminas),false) }}">
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $p->pavadinimas }}</td>
            <td>{{ $p->miestas }}</td>
            <td>{{ $p->isdavimo_data }}</td>
            @if($p->grazinimo_data != NULL)
            <td>
                <strong style="color: green;">Knyga grąžinta!</strong>
            </td>
            @elseif($skirtumas > 0)
            <td>
                Liko <strong style="color: crimson;">{{ $skirtumas }}</strong> dienų.
            </td>
            @elseif($skirtumas < 0) <td>
                <strong style="color: crimson;">Terminas praėjo!</strong>
                </td>
                @elseif($skirtumas = 0)
                <td>
                    <strong style="color: crimson;">Šiandien paskutinė grąžinimo diena!</strong>
                </td>
                @endif
                <td>{{ $p->vardas }}</td>
                <td>{{ $p->pavarde }}</td>
                <td>{{ $p->klientasnr }}</td>
                @if($p->grazinimo_data == null)
                <td><a href="{{ url('patvirtinti-grazinima-'.$p->id.'-'.$p->bookid) }}"
                        class="btn btn-primary">Grąžinimas</a> </td>
                @else
                <td>
                    <p class="btn btn-success">Grąžinta</p>
                </td>
                @endif
                @endforeach
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Second table code**

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var darbuotojai = $('#paskolinimai').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax:
            {
                url: '{!! route('get.paskolinimai') !!}'
                },


            columns: [
                { data: 'pavadinimas', name: 'pavadinimas' },
                { data: 'miestas', name: 'miestas' },
                { data: 'isdavimo_data', name: 'isdavimo_data' },
                { data: 'vardas', name: 'vardas' },
                { data: 'pavarde', name: 'pavarde' },

            ],
            'oLanguage': {
                'sSearch': "Paieška:",
                'sZeroRecords': "Nerasta atitinkančių įrašų",
                'sLengthMenu': "Rodyti _MENU_ įrašų",
                'sInfo': "Nuo _START_ iki _END_ viso _TOTAL_ įrašų",
                'sProcessing': "Apdorojama...",
                'sLoadingRecords': "Kraunama...",
                'sInfoFiltered': " - (filtruojama iš _MAX_ įrašų)",
                'oPaginate': {
                    'sFirst': "Pirmas",
                    'sLast': "Paskutinis",
                    'sNext': "Sekantis",
                    'sPrevious': "Ankstesnis"
                },

            },
            'sDom': '<"top"lfip>rt<"bottom"p><"clear">',
        });

    });
</script>
```

```html
<table id="paskolinimai" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="bg-warning">
            <th>Knygos pavadinimas</th>
            <th>Miestas</th>
            <th>Išdavimo data</th>
            <th>Vardas</th>
            <th>Pavardė</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

So how can i add Grazinimo terminas and veiksmai correctly to the second table

Comment: You need to use custom column renderers in your column defs. See the [docs](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html).

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use this package:
https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/installation

then go to section add column:
https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/add-column

and in your code will be like that:

```
 ->addColumn('intro', function(User $user) {
                if($condtion){return $result}
            })
```